# Determining variables stack or heap in C?

Tags: c, heap-memory, stack-memory

Let's say I have these variables and pointers. How do I determine which is in stack or heap?

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #define SIZE 5


    int main( void ) {

    int *zLkr;                 
    int *aLkr= NULL;
    void *sLkr= NULL;
    int num, k;
    int a[SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    zLkr = a;

    }
```

Comment: Since there is no dynamic allocation, the question is are these variables declared in a function body, or at file/global scope?

Comment: code's been changed to make better sense

Comment: Curious, what's your use case?

Comment: assume it's in a function integers/addresses are stored in 4 bytes
and starting array address is 122500

Comment: Then that is your answer, all variables are function scope variables. Nothing is dynamically allocated.

Comment: Ok so they're all stack?

Comment: If this code is inside a function (why not show a top line such as `void function(void){` to indicate that clearly?), then they're all stack variables.

Comment: There's no way to determine if an arbitrary address is part of a function's stack space in C (hell, there's no such thing as "stack space" in C), though you could use [platform-specifics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700966/thread-stack-pointer) to test.

Comment: Ok I re-edited it to put it inside a function

Comment: There is a case which contradicts the "function local variables are placed on the 'stack'" rule of tumb -- in C99, if you use *variable length arrays* (vla:s), the compiler is allowed to allocate them dynamically.

Comment: @Lindydancer: The variable has automatic duration, which is not "heap" in the sense that the asker means. For instance, when returning the address of the VLA from the function, if the caller tries to use the array, it would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your variables have automatic scope. They come from the "stack", in that the variables are no longer valid once the function returns.

Named function variables can never come from the "heap" in the sense that you mean it. The memory for a named function variable is always tied to the function scope (or the innermost block scope within the function in which the variable is declared).

A variable can be assigned a value obtained by `malloc()` or similar dynamic allocation function. The variable then points to an object that exists in the "heap". However, the named pointer variable itself is **not** in the "heap".

Sometimes the "stack" itself is dynamically allocated. Such as for a thread. Then, the memory used to allocate function local variables running within that thread is in the "heap". However, the variables themselves are still automatic, in that they are invalid once the function returns.

Comment: If I had `num = *zLkr[2];` in the function the value would be 3 but would that still be in stack?

Comment: `num` is on the stack. `*zLkr[2]` is an invalid expression. `zLkr` points to `&a[0]`. `a` is on the "stack".

Comment: so it should be `num = &zLkr[2];` so then the value would still be 0? and it would still be on the stack?

Comment: `&zLkr[2]` is a pointer to `int`, and `num` is an `int`. `num` is on the stack. `a` is on the stack (which means, each of `a`'s elements are on the stack). `zLkr` points to `&a[0]`.

Comment: I see... the array subscript notation doesn't apply to zLkr, it only applies to variable a and they are all on the stack.

Comment: `zLkr[2]` is equivalent to `*(zLkr + 2)` and is equal to `a[2]`.

Comment: Ok, so the value will be 3 because a[2] is 3

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are allocated on the **stack**

```
int main(void)
{    
    int thisVariableIsOnTheStack;

    return 0;
}
```

Variables from the **heap** are allocated via malloc somewhere in memory.  That memory can be returned to the heap, and reused by a later malloc call.

```
int main(void)
{
    char *thisVariableIsOnTheHeap = (char *) malloc(100);

    free (thisVariableIsOnTheHeap);
    return 0;
}
```

Module variables are neither.  They have a constant address in memory in one module.

```
void f1(void)
{
    /* This function doesn't see thisIsAModule */
}

int thisIsaModule = 3;

void f(void)
{
    thisIsaModule *= 2;
}

int main(void)
{
    return thisIsaModule;
}
```

Global variables are neither.   They have a constant value in memory, but can be referred to across modules.

```
extern int globalVariable;    /* This is set in some other module. */

int main(void)
{
    return globalVariable;
}
```

Comment: Without malloc, are the variables always on the stack? unless they're global?

Comment: Yes.   globals generally end up in a data segment in memory, that is not part of the heap or stack